# PHP date timestamp timezone not converted properly

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, datetime-format

So I have this code:

```
$timestamp = 1414708099;
echo $timestamp;
$date = date_make_date($timestamp, 'UTC', 'datestamp');
date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('America/New_York'));
$timestamp = $date->format('U');
echo '<br>';
echo $timestamp;
```

which is supposed to convert the timezone of the initial timestamp from UTC to new york.

but then this ends up printing

```
1414708099<br>1414708099
```

hence the timezone didnt change...

what did I do wrong?

btw it also uses Drupal 6 date_api.module: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!date!date_api.module/function/date_make_date/6

Comment: A timestamp is always UTC. You can't apply a time zone to a timestamp - consider its timezone as 0. Whatever you do, it stays 0. You asked for a date formatted with `U` - manual states this: `Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)`. You can't get seconds from Unix Epoch for New York. That number is the same for any location in the world. Now, had you formatted that date using, say, `Y-m-d H:i:s` then you would get correctly formatted time with the timezone offset for the New York. Long story short - there is no problem whatsoever here. It all works as intended.

Comment: @N.B. - Please post that as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### As per comments

A timestamp is **always UTC**. You can't apply a time zone to a timestamp - consider its timezone as 0. Whatever you do, it stays 0. You asked for a date formatted with U - manual states this:

> U: Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

You can't get seconds from Unix Epoch for New York. That number is the same for any location in the world.
Now, had you formatted that date using, say, `$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` then you would get correctly formatted time with the timezone offset for New York.

Long story short - there is no problem whatsoever here. It all works as intended.